# How to add a class to all labels in a ZF2 form

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form

I'm using a jQuery plugin that takes the text from labels associated with form elements and puts them as default text for the fields themselves. (You can find the plugin [here](https://github.com/mkdynamic/jquery-inline-labels).)

Here's the catch: it can only do this if the label has the class "inline". Now, I know I can use the following code to do this:

```
$this->add(array (
    'name' -> 'name',
    ....
    'options' => array (
        'label' => 'Name',
        'label_attributes' => array (
            'class' => 'inline'
        )
    )
));
```

This will work fine, and if it has to be done item by item, then so be it. But I was wondering if there's some way I can add the class to ALL labels associated with text and text area form elements without using JavaScript. I'm thinking this would either done by a plugin, or by looping through all the elements in the form, but I don't know how to do either.

Comment: Heck, it doesn't even have to be so precise as to only add the class to labels for text and textarea elements, as the plugin takes care of that well enough...

Answer (score 1):

You could extend the FormRow view helper.

Here is a little example:

```
use Zend\Form\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormRow;

class CustomFormRow extends FormRow
{
   public function render(ElementInterface $element) {
     ...
     $label = $element->getLabel();

     if (isset($label) && '' !== $label) {
        // Translate the label
        if (null !== ($translator = $this->getTranslator())) {
            $label = $translator->translate(
                $label, $this->getTranslatorTextDomain()
                );
        }
        $label->setAttribute('class', 'inline');
    }
    ...
    if ($this->partial) {
        $vars = array(
            'element'           => $element,
            'label'             => $label,
            'labelAttributes'   => $this->labelAttributes,
            'labelPosition'     => $this->labelPosition,
            'renderErrors'      => $this->renderErrors,
            );

        return $this->view->render($this->partial, $vars);
    }
   ...     
}
```

You could probably leave the rest as it is and you should be good to go once you add some configuration in your Module.php for your view helper.

```
public function getViewHelperConfig()   {
    return array(
        'factories' => array(

            'CustomFormRow' => function($sm) {
                return new \Application\View\Helper\CustomFormRow;
            },

            )
        );
}
```

In your template files you now have to use your viewHelper instead.

```
<?php echo $this->CustomFormRow($form->get('yourelement')); ?>
```

Comment: That's a pretty juicy answer. Not quite what I was expecting, but it did give me a lot of insight into how the new framework works. (Did I mention that I'm moving from ZF1 to ZF2 and am still really new at using the new version?)